# (PHP) How can I assign a variable with a random function and only do it one time? My variable keeps changing anytime I reference it

Tags: php, variables

The problem I seem to be having is that anytime I reference the $j variable it switches which makes sense since it literally is assigned to a function that does that. I may be just having a programmers block but, how do I make it so it generates a random number one time and I can assign it to a variable that won't change?

Thanks in advance!

```
global $wpdb;

$j = rand();

$table_name = 'quiz';
if(isset($_POST["nextpage"]) && $_POST["nextpage"]!="") {

    $j = rand();
    $nextpage = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["nextpage"]);

  switch ($nextpage) {
    case '2':
      $wpdb->insert($table_name, array('Q1score'=>$_POST[Q1],'Q2score'=>$_POST[Q2],'Q3score'=>$_POST[Q3],'ID'=>$j));

      $_SESSION['page'] = 2;

      break;
    case '3':
      $wpdb->update($table_name, array('Q4score'=>$_POST[Q4],'Q5score'=>$_POST[Q5],'Q6score'=>$_POST[Q6],'Q7score'=>$_POST[Q7]), array('ID'=>$j));
      $_SESSION['page'] = 3;
      break;

    case '4':
      $_SESSION['page'] = 4;

      break;
  }

} else {

  if (!isset($_SESSION["page"])) {
    $_SESSION["page"] = "1";
  } else {
    /* do nothing */
  }

}
```

Comment: "won't change" throughout one run of the script or "won't change" ever, across multiple requests?

Comment: _one time_ ever?  _one time_ per user?  _one time_ what?

Comment: Won't change through one run of the script. So whenever I reference to update the database I don't want that random number to change as I''m using it for the unique ID in the database

Comment: @ZacharyToney Put it into your session?

Comment: instead of random why don't you send last id also through `POST`, it will help you in query and  pagination and  cut lot of problems for you. I am telling because you are using that random number for id matches in your query

Comment: So just do:

    'ID'=>$_POST[$j]; 
?

Comment: @Machavity

Suggesting to add session variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `isset()` to see if it's already been defined in this scope.

```
if ( !isset( $j ) ) $j = rand();
```

Populate a `$_SESSION[]` variable if you want to maintain across multiple page loads during one session.

```
if ( !isset( $_SESSION['j'] ) ) $_SESSION['j'] = rand(); // expects session_start() to be called somewhere above
$j = $_SESSION['j'];
```

Pick one or the other.

```
global $wpdb;

if ( !isset( $_SESSION['j'] ) ) $_SESSION['j'] = rand(); // expects session_start() to be called somewhere above
$j = $_SESSION['j'];

$table_name = 'quiz';
if(isset($_POST["nextpage"]) && $_POST["nextpage"]!="") {

    /* $j = rand(); remove this assignment */
    $nextpage = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["nextpage"]);

  switch ($nextpage) {
    case '2':
      $wpdb->insert($table_name, array('Q1score'=>$_POST[Q1],'Q2score'=>$_POST[Q2],'Q3score'=>$_POST[Q3],'ID'=>$j));

      $_SESSION['page'] = 2;

      break;
    case '3':
      $wpdb->update($table_name, array('Q4score'=>$_POST[Q4],'Q5score'=>$_POST[Q5],'Q6score'=>$_POST[Q6],'Q7score'=>$_POST[Q7]), array('ID'=>$j));
      $_SESSION['page'] = 3;
      break;

    case '4':
      $_SESSION['page'] = 4;

      break;
  }

} else {

  if (!isset($_SESSION["page"])) {
    $_SESSION["page"] = "1";
  } else {
    /* do nothing */
  }

}
```

Comment: I like this suggestion. Worked perfectly. However is there a better way to go about this so future programmers can know?